# With OpenXML how do I get the StyleIndex of an existing style in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I am editing an existing excel spreadsheet with an **existing** cell Style in it called "**myFavouriteStyle**".

Using OpenXML SDK V2 c# how do I find the **StyleIndex** of that style so I can apply it to new cell(s) I add to the spreadsheet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a reference to a Cell with the "myFavouriteStyle" applied to it you could:

```
public static int GetCellStyleIndex(Cell theCell)
{ 
  int cellStyleIndex;
  if (theCell.StyleIndex == null) 
  {                               
    cellStyleIndex = 0;           
  }                              
  else
  {
    cellStyleIndex = (int)theCell.StyleIndex.Value;
  }     

  return cellStyleIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I had already thought of that 1, just reluctant to go that way as a user may change or remove that format from the cell in question.

Comment: Is it an option to make a protected sheet containing a cell for each style you want to use in your code?